# Правило написания в глаголах сочетания букв чу, ча

Tags: правописание

Правило, по которому надо писать чу, а не ча в слове мечут (икру).

Answer (score 2):

Выбор гласных после шипящих по правилу ЧА-ЩА, ЧУ-ЩУ применяется для ударной позиции гласного.

Безударный звук надо предварительно проверить, здесь в одной позиции как бы две орфограммы: проверка звука и выбор гласного для проверенного звука.

Метать - (1) гл. 1-го спряжения, окончание УТ/ЮТ, (2) после шипящей Ч согласно правилу пишем окончание УТ.

Comment: Спасибо!!!